# from object value into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object value

```
foreach($this->promo_cart->contents() as $produks){
    foreach($this->login_sess->contents() as $val):
        $idex = array_unique(explode('_', $produks['prod_name']));
        if($val['id']==$idex[2]) {
            echo $val[id]; //result is 314314315
        }
    endforeach;
}
```

how I make an array from that result, like

```
array
(
  [0] => 314
  [1] => 314
  [2] => 315
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add elements to an array like this:

```
$foo = array(); // start with empty array
$foo[] = 'bar'; // added element to array => array([0] => "bar")
```

So in your case you can do this:

```
$my_array = array();

foreach($this->promo_cart->contents() as $produks)
{
  foreach($this->login_sess->contents() as $val)
  {
    $idex = array_unique(explode('_', $produks['prod_name']));

    if($val['id']==$idex[2]) {
      $my_array[] = $val[id];
    }
  }
}
```

`$my_array` will contain:

```
array
(
  [0] => 314
  [1] => 314
  [2] => 315
)
```

Answer (score 1):

create new array and push the required value to that array with `[]`
try this

```
 $tempArray=array();  //<---create new array
 foreach($this->promo_cart->contents() as $produks){
     foreach($this->login_sess->contents() as $val):
    $idex = array_unique(explode('_', $produks['prod_name']));
    if($val['id']==$idex[2]) {
        $tempArray[] = $val[id];  //<----push value to array.
    }
     endforeach;
  }
  print_r($tempArray);
```